# Reset Boolean List

Tags: .net, generic-list

I was surprised to find that the following code did not work:

```
private List<bool> _IsSet = new List<bool>();
public void ClearIsSet()
{
    _IsSet.ForEach(x => x = false);
}
```

After calling `ClearIsSet`, the `true` values are still in the list.

I know I can make it work with a `for` loop.

Is there a way to make this work without a `for` loop? If not, why not?

**EDIT:**

After writing this extension function, I didn't use it.

```
[Extension()]
public IList<T> ReplaceAll<T>(IList<T> Source, T Value)
{
    IList<T> Replacement = Source.Select(x => Value).ToList();
    Source.Clear();
    Source.AddRange(Replacement);
    return Source;
}
```

I just used:

```
_IsSet = _IsSet.Select(x => false).ToList()
```

because `Select` really is `ReplaceAll` in a fluent chain.

However, you could just say:

```
_IsSet.ReplaceAll(false);
```

whereas you can't do that with `Select`, but the code in `ReplaceAll` seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ForEach` takes an `Action` and performs the `Action` on each item in the `List`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

An `Action` returns no values.  What you're doing in your sample code is basically taking a temporary argument, `x`, and assigning it to a new value.  This variable `x` simply receives values from the `List`; it is not a reference to the value that's in the `List`, since `bool` is not a reference type.  Assigning a new value to your argument variable `x` has no impact on the original list value, no more than if you assigned a new value to a method argument elsewhere in your code.

Even if `bool` was a reference type, `ForEach` wouldn't assign any value back to that position in the list.  You could mutate mutable objects in the `List`, but you couldn't replace values in the `List`.

The function you're likely looking for is [`IEnumerable<T>.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx).  It accepts a function that maps from the `IEnumerable`'s element type to some new type, and returns an `IEnumerable` containing the transformed elements.

Comment: So the code would be `_IsSet = _IsSet.Select(b => false)`?

Comment: Actually `_IsSet = _IsSet.Select(Function(x) False).ToList`

Answer (score 1):

The foreach loop creates a local copy for it's iterator variable and you assign a new value to that copy. That does not change the element in the list.

You could use

```
_IsSet = Enumerable.Repeat(false, _IsSet.Count).ToList();
```

or if you need *that* exact list instance:

```
var count = _IsSet.Count;
_IsSet.Clear();
_IsSet.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(false, count));
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact that i's a value type; it wouldn't work for a reference type either. It's because the parameter to the lambda is passed by value, not by reference.